# undefined method recreate_versions! for :string in carrierwave and rails 4.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I am getting a:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show
undefined method `recreate_versions!' for "img1.jpg":String
```

when I call:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.photo.recreate_versions!
end
```

in my mounted uploader. My table column is called photo with a data type of String and is called by attr_accessible in my User model. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Here is my full code:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include Sprockets::Rails::Helper

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url

    "fallback/" + [version_name, "img1.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :mini_thumb do 
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 40]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end

  version :default do 
    process :resize_to_limit => [250, 250]
  end

  User.all.each do |user|
     user.photo.recreate_versions!
   end
end
```

Maybe I am not supposed to call recreate_versions from the mounted uploader?

EDIT:

Running

```
User.first.photo.class
```

in the console outputs:

```
  User Load (10.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (10.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => PhotoUploader
```

Then iterating through each user and calling recreate_versions!:

```
2.0.0p0 :003 > User.all.each do |user|
2.0.0p0 :004 >       user.photo.recreate_versions!
2.0.0p0 :005?>   end
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass
```

After checking for nil in the rails console this worked (still not sure where to put it though):

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.photo.recreate_versions! if user.photo.present?
end
```

Comment: Probably want to update to Rails 4 RC1.

Comment: I will soon, but would that make a difference for this specific problem?

Comment: No, that would not affect your current issue. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one thing I've noticed in your code is the placement of the

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.photo.recreate_versions!
end
```

Are you actually including this in your `PhotoUploader` class? If so, that might be your problem. Try removing that code from the Uploader. Now, open up the rails console (run the command `rails console` from the command line while in your app folder). Type `User.first.photo.class`. The return value should be `PhotoUploader`. If it is, then the above should work as well. Copy and paste it in the console and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the output from the rails console, after removing that block:

2.0.0p0 :006 > User.photo.class

NoMethodError: undefined method `photo' for #<Class:0x007ff3b12fb9d8>

Comment: Sorry, that was an error on my part. Assuming that you have users in your database, execute this command in the console: `User.first.photo.class`

Comment: Ok, after checking for nil that worked (not all my users have photos). See the edits in my question above. Where would you recommend I place that block of code though? Or should you just run it in the rails console whenever you need to recreate the versions?

Comment: Really depends on your situation. To me, the recreation of all versions for all users sounds like an administration task that you would only have to do once and a while, so I would either just run the code from the console, or put it in a rake task. If you want to expose this functionality to your view/controller layer, I would put it in the User class as a static method `def self.recreate_all_versions <your code> end` .

Answer (score 0):

In User Model  write

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have that in my user model.

Answer (score 0):

Your current issue is that you are expecting photo to be an uploader before it is. You can't call recreate_versions! on it during the class definition of the thing it is going to use as proxy for user.photo.

Once the uploader class is defined during the setup, you can then call user.photo.recreate_versions! assuming you mounted that uploader.

Comment: Thanks. Where would you recommend I call recreate_versions! though? Not sure where to put it...